# How to check communication between tabs (duplicate, refresh tab) - Angular

Tags: angular, browser, tabs

​
Currently I am taking online tests for students. I'm having difficulty checking whether the student copies the current tab or refreshes the current tab.

Because if students copy 10 identical exam tabs on the same browser, the server will be overloaded.

Currently, each tab will have a url and when duplicated, it will have the same url, so I want to manage the differences between tabs, each tab will have a unique point to distinguish it, such as when creating a new tab, it will create an Id. of that tab so I can distinguish between tabs that have the same url but different Id.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFAmW.jpg)

[image: img2]

I tried using across tab but it didn't work for my project. I need help from everyone

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to address this problem is by using `localstorage`. You can store a number, which increases any time a user opens your page and decreases on reload/close. By that, you can track how many tabs a user opened of your site.

Try this inside your `AppComponent`s `onInit` or `constructor`:

```js
const tabsOpened = localStorage.getItem('tabsOpen');
console.log('tabs opened', tabsOpened); // here you can see how many tabs are opened currently 
// -> Take some action here. To prevent more server requests

if(tabsOpened == null) {
   localStorage.setItem('tabsOpen', '1');
} else {
   localStorage.setItem('tabsOpen', (parseInt(tabsOpened) + 1).toString());
}

// This will decrease your counter on tabs closed or reload
window.onunload = () => {
   const tabsOpened = localStorage.getItem('tabsOpen');
   if(tabsOpened != null) {
      localStorage.setItem('tabsOpen', (parseInt(tabsOpened) - 1).toString());
   }
}
```

You can redirect to an error page at the point of the error, or do something else.

Please test this code yourself and make sure your users have a way to bypass any errors.

Remember: Your angular application still needs to load initially from your server. So anytime you open a new tab there will be some server load. Nevertheless, you can for example prevent new tabs from making more server calls.

Comment: Thank you so much but it isn't best solution because when I duplicate a tab with the same url, the variable tabsOpen will be overwritten, so you still can't distinguish between the two tabs (, I want to have a difference for each tab to be able to distinguish it as an id, because I will send the id to the server, to check if the tabs have the same session but have different ids.)

Comment: After reading `openTabs` for the first time, you can save this number in a service to keep it constant. With this `id` you can distinguish the tab used.